# Issues SubStrings and outofboundsexception error

Tags: java, android

I have some code to display the first ten characters of a string on a button. but I get the out of boiunds exception error when the string is less than 10 characters or null.

I thought a simple IF statement would fix it, but it doesn't seem to have. Could someone point out my problem? Thanks

I checked with the android developers reference, and it doesn't state a way to get around this

```
Button item1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontext1);
String ellipsed = PrefConnector.readString(this, PrefConnector.ONE, null);

if(ellipsed.length() < 1) ellipsed = "Touch to edit";
if(ellipsed.length() > 10) ellipsed = ellipsed.substring(0, 10) + "...";

item1.setText(ellipsed);
```

Comment: Post your log and identify where it's breaking. Is `ellipsed` non-null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a null-pointer exception, then there must be cases where ellipsed is null.

Even if ellipsed is never null, your code above has a problem: If ellipsed.length()<10, you change it to "Touch to edit", but then you check for length>10, and "Touch to edit".length()>10, so short strings would always end up "Touch to e..."

In any case, I think what you want to say is

```
if (ellipsed==null || ellipsed.length()==0)
  ellipsed="Touch to edit";
else if (ellipsed.length()>10)
  ellipsed=ellipsed.substring(0,10)+"...";
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked. you may want to edit your answer for people who get to this page through a google search in the future. You haven't completed the statements, IE added in the semi-colons where needed!

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the fix. That's what happens when you're brain gets infected with VB.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try...

```
    if(ellipsed.length() < 1)
        ellipsed = "Touch to edit";
    else 
        ellipsed = ellipsed.substring(1, ellipsed.length()) + "...";
```

Comment: This didn't work. Still get a null exception when the string is empty

Answer (score 0):

Basically you take the substring of the first 10 characters and you wonder why you get an exception if you try  to get the 10 first characters of a string with length less than 10? From the oracle docs:

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or
>   endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or
>   beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Comment: I know that, but I'm looking for a way to get past this

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ellipsed != null && ellipsed.length() >10)
    ellipsed = ellipsed.substring(0, 10) + "...";
else 
     ellipsed = "Touch to edit";
```

Comment: +1, correct answer.  (I'm out of daily votes so I can't actually upvote your answer, sorry).

Comment: This works for when it's null, but not if the string is between 0 and 10 characters

Comment: @Vulcan: haha, how could I be so blind!!
It worked for me though!!

Comment: @user1195777 Your specification for when the string is 0-10 characters was a bit vague; do you want it to remain unchanged if that's the condition met?